# Full horizontal page carousel bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I try to build a responsive one page using bootstrap that scrolls horizontally and every mouse scroll will switch to next page, best way i found so far to achieve this is to use carousel. The problem is that my carousel skips "pages". is there any way to restrict mouse scroll event to move only 100vw per scroll? or any other creative ideas how to approach this kind of build?

Any help will be much appreciated.Thanks in advance

This what i have so far:
https://codepen.io/xxannxx/pen/mxJWae

Html:

```html
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>
          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
              <div class="item active">
                  <div class="container-fluid">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-lg-6">
                              <div class="aquamarine">
                    
                              </div><!--article end-->
                          </div><!--column end-->
                          <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="blue"></div>
                          
                          </div><!--column end-->
          </div><!--row two end-->
      </div><!--container two end-->
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                      CAPTION - information about the image
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                  <div class="container-fluid">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-lg-6">
                              <div class="pink">
                    
                              </div><!--article end-->
                          </div><!--column end-->
                          <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="purple"></div>
                          
                          </div><!--column end-->
          </div><!--row two end-->
      </div><!--container two end-->
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                      CAPTION - information about the image
                  </div>
              </div>
              
              <div class="item">
                  <div class="container-fluid">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-lg-6">
                              <div class="yellow">
                    
                              </div><!--article end-->
                          </div><!--column end-->
                          <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="orange"></div>
                          
                          </div><!--column end-->
          </div><!--row two end-->
      </div><!--container two end-->
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                      CAPTION - information about the image
                  </div>
              </div>
              
          </div>
<!-- Controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
      </div>
      </body>
```

Css:

```css
.aquamarine {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}

.blue {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color:skyblue;
}

.pink {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color:lightpink;
}

.purple {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color:plum;
}

.yellow {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color:yellow;
}

.orange {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color:orange;
}
.right.carousel-control, .left.carousel-control {
    display: none;
}

.carousel-indicators li { 
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

JS:

```js
          $('#myCarousel').carousel({
              interval: false
          });
          
          
          $('#myCarousel').bind('mousewheel', function(e)
    {
        if(event.wheelDelta>0) {
            $(this).carousel('next');
        }else if(event.wheelDelta<0){
            $(this).carousel('prev');
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to use this js lightweight plugin which does exactly what you want and is really simple to use : https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#page1

Comment: thanks for the try, i tested this one but seems the horizontal scrolling working only on slides which not really fitting my content and i need the horizontal extension. any way maybe it will be useful for someone, found this jquery plugin that support horizontal scrolling:  http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html